# LINQ - The difference between .Select(n => n.Name) and .Select(n => new { n.Name } );

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

I am completely new to Linq and wondering if you can help me understand the difference between the following Linq?  For example...

```
//normal select
var contacts = entity.Contacts.Select(n => n.FirstName);

//select new
var contacts2 = entity.Contacts.Select(n => new { n.FirstName });

//normal select output
foreach (var c in contacts)
    Response.Write(c + "<br/>");

//select new output
foreach (var c in contacts2)
    Response.Write(c.FirstName + "<br/>");
```

The only difference I can see is that in the normal select, the firstname (string) is stored in the collection, whereas in the select new, a contact object is stored in the collecton and the firstname being accessed by its property.  Also the select new returns the properties only selected in the statement.

Another difference I noticed is that you can return multiple specific properties in the select new.

In what scenario would you choose one over the other?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Here's a scenario: `select new { n.FirstName, n.LastName }`

Answer (score 20):

`n => n.FirstName` gives you a `string`

`n => new { n.FirstName }` gives you an [anonymous type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx), with one `string` property called `FirstName`

In general, an anonymous type with just one property is probably not what you're looking for, so I'd go for the first option.

Answer (score 6):

To support Richard Ev's answer:

If you are not familiar with Anonymous types, crack up ildasm and give your exe as an input to it.

You will get something like this:

[image]

The thing that you see starting with <>f_AnonymousType() is the one that Richard Ev is talking about. Your syntax of `new` got translated into a new class (the name was decided by compiler). That is why `var` keyword is so helpful working with anonymous type.